# How to add images to taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, images, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries, multi-taxonomy-query

**Q:** Is it possible to add images to all of my taxonomies (default and custom ones)?

**Note:** I do not want to use any plugins (not my favourite solution for design related matters).

**Usage:** I want to create really practical custom post type portfolio with custom taxonomies. For example, custom taxonomy - clients, so if multiple projects from same customer/client would be realted and at the same time I could use the taxonomy as showcase of my clients. The similar usage would go with almost of my taxonomies (whether to have taxonomy archive with image and description on).

Any good practice advice here? Thanks in advance

**Clarification:** I want to add images to the terms of my custom taxonomies. Example, custom post type 'portfolio' with custom taxonomy 'clients', where each 'client' term (lets say Adidas) would have its logo attached.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean, e.g. do you want to add an image to the 'category taxonomy' or do you want to add an image to 'category terms'? Note that a particular obstacle to this would be the lack of a taxonomy or taxonomy term meta

Comment: Ah, so basically featured images for taxonomy terms

Comment: I also like to use as little plugins as possible, but I do also like clean solutions and when it comes to taxonomy sometimes the solutions aren't always clean cut. If a client needs taxonomy images I use [Categories Images plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/) if you change your mind on using a plugin.

Comment: Ill try playing with the answered option. If it will end up being even more messy code i will consider this plugin. thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting from Wordpress 4.4, you can use [add_term_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_term_meta) function to store metadata for a term. This is basically a key-value pair information which is stored in `wp_termmeta` table.

**Original Answer(Prior to WP 4.4)**

Wordpress doesn't have the option to add extra information to taxonomies. There isn't any `taxonomy_meta` table. So, you have two options.

- Create a new custom table and save the extra information(image link) there.
- You can also use `options` table  to store the information.

You can follow this post of as it shows how to implement what you are trying to do: http://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way/

Comment: That is actually pretty good. Still very hacky.

Comment: @nerijusgood As there isn't default support, you have to hack. Maybe you can remove most of the options and only use the part that you need for storing image link.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete, since it's pre WordPress 4.4, which introduced terms meta.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin to add a custom field (an image field) to your custom taxonomy group.

Comment: Link only answers are not quite recommended.

Comment: As a Developer i think I should avoid it

Answer (score 3):

WordPress 4.4 introduced Term meta, which means we can now add custom fields to terms just like we do with posts, without hacky code.

Currently though the WP Tax/Term backend UI lacks of an Image selector (and might never have it), but [here you'll find a good guide](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/how-to-use-term-meta-data-in-wordpress/) on what was added in WP 4.4

If you won't build your own plugin, then some existing plugins may have already switched to it. I'd advise using a plugin that has already switched to this, e.g. [WP Term Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-term-images/), rather than others that may still use their own DB tables, or worse, WP options tables.